# Event in jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, codepen

I have this code in my program, but the event isn't doing anything from the JS in Codepen, but when I paste it in the javascript console from Debug View, it works.

```
$('.peg-row--selected').children().click(function(e) {
  console.log("hi");
  $(e.target).attr('data-peg',$('.peg-selector--selected').attr('data-peg'));
});
```

Comment: You should read this article before asking any further questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: could you share the Codepen ?

Comment: Yeah http://codepen.io/spacegeek224/pen/RKgXyQ/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your element exist before you bind the event, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.peg-row--selected').children().click(function(e) {
    console.log("hi");
    $(e.target).attr('data-peg',$('.peg-selector--selected').attr('data-peg'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Should I do that with all my events?

Comment: Yes, but they can be inside the same ready (also written `$(function() { .... });`

Comment: How can you attempt to answer the question without full context of the environment?

Comment: the thing is you cannot bind an event to an element that doesn't exist. So for all events your have to ensure that the element you are binding it to exist. It could be like this if the element exist as soon as the page is loaded, or something else if your element element will be rendered later.. it depends on your architecture

Comment: @seemly, experience ahah.. more seriously I didn't know that's why I have said "TRY this"